# Problem with jquery appendTo function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several textareas on my page and I use jquery **focus** function to clear the textarea when someone clicks it. Here is the code:

```
$("textarea.text").focus(function() {
    if( $(this).attr("has_desc") == "false" ) {
        $(this).val("");
        $(this).attr("has_desc", "true");
    }
});
```

The user has the ability to dynamically add new textareas and I use **appendTo** function to add new one. The problem is that the above code doesn't work for the appended textareas! The HTML code is exactly the same as for the forms that aren't added dynamically! Can anyone please tell what is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.focus will not work for dynamically created elements. You could use .live('focus', function() ...

Comment: No prob. You should accept the answer if it's the right one you're looking for. :)